# Organizing changes from one working branch into features branches

Tags: git

I am fresh to git. I have a branch called "feature" which has multiple files changed, created and deleted. I am working with task that in the end required not only creating new files but refactoring existing ones. In the end I have files "a, b, c" that are new feature related and "d, e, f" that are refactored. I want to keep all changes to those files in my "feature" branch but also split d, e, f file changes to separate branches and create separate pull requests for those changes.  I have no commits yet.

What I tried is to checkout "feature" branch into "d" branch and commit and push changes for "d file", then check out to "e" and commit and push "e file" and so on. It worked well for splitting "d", "e", "f" into separate branches, but in the end I left with "a, b, c" changes uncommitted and checking out back to "feature" branch leaves me only with these changes instead of all of initial changes.

I know this is not the way to achieve what I want. Should I first commit all changes in "feature" branch one by one and then checkout to new branches "d, e, f" and cherry pick commit I want from "feature branch".

**End result:**

Feature branch - a, b, c, d, e, f changes (commits?)

D branch - d changes

E branch - e changes

F branch - f changes

What is the correct way to achive this? Can I stash changes and apply them in d, e, f branches leaving only needed changes and discarding other?

Comment: Well, probably the best solution is to use `stash`. One tip, use `apply` instead of `pop` so you do not lose content.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you have `feature` branch and `git log` as the following:

```
<commit-id>      feature       d, e and f file added
...
...
so on
```

`git status` in `feature` branch as to:

```
modified:   d.txt
modified:   e.txt
modified:   f.txt

created:    a.txt
created:    b.txt
created:    c.txt
```

If you use `git stash` command, your modified files added to stash area and now `git status` in `feature` branch as to:

```
created:    a.txt
created:    b.txt
created:    c.txt
```

you create `d`, `e` and `f` branches in `feature` branch

```
git switch -c d
git switch -c e
git switch -c f
```

If you use `git stash apply` command above any branch, changes removed from stash area and they are moved while you switch branches.

You commit these changes in related branch, you will reach the goal.

```
(d branch) git add d.file
(d branch) git commit -m "d.file refactoring"

(e branch) git add e.file
(e branch) git commit -m "e.file refactoring"

(f branch) git add f.file
(f branch) git commit -m "f.file refactoring"
```

Finally, `git log` :

**feature branch**

```
<commit-id>      feature       d, e and f file added
...
...
so on
```

**d branch**

```
<commit-id>      d             d file refactoring
<commit-id>      feature       d, e and f file added
...
...
so on
```

**e branch**

```
<commit-id>      e             e file refactoring
<commit-id>      feature       d, e and f file added
...
...
so on
```

**f branch**

```
<commit-id>      f             f file refactoring
<commit-id>      feature       d, e and f file added
...
...
so on
```

Comment: Feature branch have no commits yet. It is checked from main. Three files added and three edited. I want to see these added files and edited files in feature branch for dev/testing purposes, but split d, e, f to separate branches and make PR to merge into main branch. In the end I will merge my main into feature branch when d, e, f are merged into main and feature branch should show only a, b, c changes as d, e, f will be up to date with main. So with your method in the end if I apply stash on feature branch again a, b, c, d, e, f should appear in feature branch?

Comment: @Andyally No d, e and f already commited so why should they appear?